# How to add a label to Seaborn Heatmap color bar?

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn

If I have the following data and Seaborn Heatmap:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'x':(1,2,3,4),'y':(1,2,3,4),'z':(14,15,23,2)})

sns.heatmap(data.pivot_table(index='y', columns='x', values='z'))
```

How do I add a label to the colour bar?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You could set it afterwards after collecting it from an `ax`, or simply pass a label in `cbar_kws` like so.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'x':(1,2,3,4),'y':(1,2,3,4),'z':(14,15,23,2)})

sns.heatmap(data.pivot_table(index='y', columns='x', values='z'), 
                             cbar_kws={'label': 'colorbar title'})
```

[image]

It is worth noting that `cbar_kws` can be handy for setting other attributes on the colorbar such as tick frequency or formatting.

Answer (score 18):

You can use:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(data.pivot_table(index='y', columns='x', values='z'))
ax.collections[0].colorbar.set_label("Hello")
```