# How to output more than one heatmap and have a description for the colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

uniform_data1 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax1 = sns.heatmap(uniform_data1)

uniform_data2 = np.random.rand(5, 6)
ax2 = sns.heatmap(uniform_data2)
```

which outputs a sort of "combined" heatmap with a "combined" colorbar.

How do I output the 1st heatmap followed by the 2nd heatmap (located below the 1st one) if I need to have all my code in one cell like in the above? I need this because I am generating a report.

Also, how do I have a description for the colorbar?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)

np.random.seed(0)

uniform_data1 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax1 = sns.heatmap(uniform_data1, ax=axes[0])

uniform_data2 = np.random.rand(5, 6)
ax2 = sns.heatmap(uniform_data2, ax=axes[1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**
For the description, may be with `axes.legend()` ?

Comment: Many thanks @david, `plt.subplots()` worked! With the description, `axes.legend()` didn't work, but managed to find another way which did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092218/how-to-add-a-label-to-seaborn-heatmap-color-bar